# permission propagation when dumping text into file

Tags: permissions, sudo

If I do:

```
sudo mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -pwelcome1 mydb > dump.sql
```

I get:

```
-bash: dump.sql: Permission non accordée
```

However if I `sudo` to `su` first, it works fine. It seems that `sudo` does not propagate to the `>` command.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute the `bash` shell (remember the full path) 
quoting `""` all your command as argument with the option `-c`

```
sudo /bin/bash -c "mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -pwelcome1 mydb > dump.sql"
```

Comment: ok, I didn't know that. It works, thanks. Why do I have to do that ?

Comment: I believe that when you invoke the command `sudo` as _normal user_, `sudo` calls what it follows, but the redirection of the output `>` is the redirection of the `sudo` command, so it belongs to the _normal user_. Of course it's only a way to do it. e.g. you can _dump_ the file where you have the right to write. (`...  >/home/Sam/dump.sql`)